# RadioButton with Javascript (MVC3)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button, maskedinput

I'm working with C# and MVC3

I have a RadioButton, and depending on the option selected I need to change the mask of a textbox.
I'm using Masked Input Plugin for jQuery.

How can I do this? I have to develop it on the Controller or on the .cshtml?

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
        @Html.Label("Test Label")
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.RbTest, "F", true)

        @Html.Label("Test Label 2")
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.RbTest, "J")

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LabelBla)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NeedMask)
    </div>
```

If I choose "F" (First RadioButton) I want to have a mask.
If I choose "J" (Second RadioButton) I want another mask.

I need to mask the Editor: "NeedMask"

Comment: You need some JavaScript for that.

Comment: Ya, I tried: <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#RbTest').click(function (event) {
            Alert("Wow!");
        })
    });

</script>

But fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!

```
@Html.RadioButton("RbTest", "F", true, new { @onclick = "Mask1()" })
@Html.RadioButton("RbTest", "J", false, new { @onclick = "Mask2()" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is a jquery function to addClass() and removeClass(). So you could do something like:

```
$(".f").click(function(){
       this.addClass("NeedMask");
    });
```

I'm actually at work atm but this should get you started in the right direction. I'd check the jQuery docs for help on masking (you'll also want to use `$(".J").removeClass("NeedMask")`

Comment: you will either want to place that code inside of a referenced .js file, or inside of a <script type="text/javascript"></script> tag